# nodejs: how can I only set redirect to basic url on expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://www.google.com");
});

app.use("/app/v1", app);
```

I have this code and trying to redirect only on `localhost:9999/`. However, when I do `localhost:9999/app/v1`, I still get redirected by the app. Is there anyway that I can set the express to redirect only when the incoming url is just `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.use` mounts a [middleware for the specified path](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).

The express application performs the middleware for the root path and other paths under the root path.

```
/
/app/v1
/any-other-path
```

Using regular expressions, you can ensure that the middleware is  performed only for the root path like so:

```js
app.use("/$", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://www.google.com");
});
```

Another way is to configure a route handler instead of a middleware using
[`app.get`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route) or other relevant request methods.

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://www.google.com");
});
```